# Explain some All countries excluding residents in BIS Debt Securities Data

Tags: statistics, debt, bonds, definition

In the [BIS Debt Securities statistics](https://www.bis.org/statistics/index.htm):

In both column "issueresidence" and column "issuenationality" there is a category called "**All countries excluding residents**". I do not understand what it means. What is it used for? although I have read through the report going with the data.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is not particularly helpful - perhaps you mean something like https://stats.bis.org/?m=6%257C346%257C644#ppq=CBS_IB_INT_C_BY_SEC_TYP_IB;pv=11~10,9~0,0,0~name

"All countries excluding residents" is a phrase BIS use for *international* debt securities, so represents debt or similar instruments issued by somebody in one country and held by somebody else in a different country, i.e. excluding residents (human or corporate) of the same county

Note that residents of the same country may have a different nationality or be owned by non-residents.  So for example if an American-owned subsidiary incorporated in London issues a debt security to a German-owned subsidiary incorporated in London denominated in Japanese Yen, this would be excluded from these statistics since the two banks are both resident in the UK. But if the American-owned bank in London holds a debt security issued by an American bank in New York, this should not be excluded, and should count as a US liability to the UK

BIS provides a [glossary](https://www.bis.org/statistics/glossary.htm?&selection=260&scope=Statistics&c=a&base=term), which is sometimes helpful and sometimes less so

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. The link I posted actually leads to all sorts of data that BIS has, including the Debt Securities. The link you gave was about Consolidated Banking Statistics, not exactly what I meant but also has the category "all countries excluding residents", so thank you very much.